# Incorrect Euler Totient Function definition?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, functions

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function), definition of Euler's totient function (or Euler's totient function) is:

> Euler's totient function is an arithmetic function that counts the positive integers less than or **equal to $n$** that are relatively prime to $n$, ie if $n$ is a positive integer, then $\phi(n)$ is the number of integers $k$ in the range $1 ≤ k ≤ n$ for which the greatest common divisor $gcd(n, k) = 1$.

Why does the definition specifically mention that the **relative prime number to $n$ can be equal to $n$** (Check the highlighted area in the definition)?

I think that for any positive number $n$ the value of $gcd(n,n)$ will always be $n$, so $n$ is never relatively prime to $n$. So why does it state that range of $k$ is $1 ≤ k ≤ n$ instead of $1 ≤ k < n$

Am I correct in making this assumption? Is there any exception?

Comment: Exception is $n=1$.  I would use the number between $0$ and $n-1$ that are relatively prime to $n$. Same function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We want $\phi(1)=1$ cause that makes $\phi$ multiplicative.